# asp.net MVC: TryUpdateModel doesn't bind DateTime properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I'm having issues with a date property not binding correctly using TryUpdateModel in MVC.

I am using a POCO class and a corresponding viewModel.

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name must be entered.")]
    public string ContactGivenName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name must be entered.")]
    public string ContactFamilyName { get; set; }

    ....

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

}
```

the entity class:

```
public class Contact 
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string ContactFamilyName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string ContactGivenName { get; set; }

    ...

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

}
```

and in my controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public virtual ActionResult UpdateContact(int id, FormCollection form)
    {
        //Find a customer whose CustomerID is equal to the id action parameter
        var c = _contactService.Get(id);

        if (c != null)
        {

            //Perform model binding (fill the customer properties and validate it).
            if (TryUpdateModel(c, form))
            {
```

The _contactService.Get returns the instance from EntityFramework.

The TryUpdateModel binds string properties like first and last name correctly, but despite a lot of tries, I can't get it to bind the date of birth.

I suspect it's a formatting issue of some kind but cannot find what it is.

When I debug, I can see in the FormCollection that the date is correctly there, with the value that was input in the view so the data is definitely passed on to the controller.

the value passed to the controller is in format :
yyyy-MM-dd

I tried modifying this on the fly with multiple format without success.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, I have no idea why you're using TryUpdateModel.. That's pretty archaic.

Second, it sounds to me like you have not set your culture to accept the format you expect.  Add the following to your web.config if your browser is defaults already set to the correct culture:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiculture="auto" enableclientbasedculture="true">
    </globalization>
</system.web>
```

If you want to force a culture, then set the culture you wish in this setting.

Comment: Thanks, why is it archaic ? I usually pass the model back as parameter, in that case it wasn't my code so I had to accomodate with the TryUpdateModel. I can probably change it and use automapper to map to my entity class.

Answer (score 0):

the globalization didn't help and is actually already set, however I realized there's a custom binder for Datetime and that is probably where my problem is.

thanks